# FuelPHP ORM - Property not found

Tags: php, orm, fuelphp

I'm trying to build models using ORM in FuelPHP, never used ORM before, so not sure of certain aspects.

I have a table Project and a table Revision. Now, projects have multiple revisions, revision has only one project.

However, I have an additional link between Project and Revision where I always keep the ID of the latest revision in my Project table.

My tables look like this:

```
projects
- id
- latest_revision_id
- ...

revisions
- id
- project_id
- ...
```

The project model:

```
class Model_Project extends Orm\Model
{

    protected static $_belongs_to = array(
        'latest_revision' => array(
            'key_from' => 'latest_revision_id'
        ),
    );

    protected static $_has_many = array(
    'revisions',
    );

...

}
```

The revision model:

```
class Model_Revision extends \Orm\Model
{

    protected static $_belongs_to = array(
        'project',
    );

    protected static $_has_one = array(
        'project' => array(
            'key_to' => 'latest_revision_id',
        ),
    );

}
```

However, when I try to access:

```
$project->latest_revision
```

It gives me an OutOfBoundException: `OutOfBoundsException [ Error ]: Property "latest_revision_id" not found for Model_Project.`

Am I missing something?

Thanks!

Comment: is it correct?
<< products >>
- id
- latest_revision_id
- ...

It seems that your table name is incorrect

Comment: Oups! Sorry for the confusion, that was just a typo in my post. The real table name is projects

Comment: I havn't used fuel for a while, when I'll came back home I'll see my old project for the solution :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like I had to add the latest_revision_id to my $_properties array. Which I swear I tried before posting the question, but guess I had another problem at the time!

So my project model now:

```
protected static $_belongs_to = array(
    'latest_revision' => array(
        'key_from' => 'latest_revision_id',
        'model_to' => 'Model_Revision',
    ),
);

protected static $_has_many = array(
    'revisions',
);

protected static $_properties = array(
    'id', 
    ..., 
    'latest_revision_id',
);
```